# How does one go about evaluating the limits of nonelementary antiderivatives of functions?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, error-function

We obviously know the following to be equal:

$$\lim_{z \to \pm\infty} \text{erf}(z) = \pm1$$

But as far as I'm aware, the only way we know how to calculate any given value of the error function is to approximate it. How do we know the limits at *infinities* without any way to evaluate it algabraically?

Comment: Because we can actually calculate that limit directly, or at the least we can compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$ and cut the area in half. See [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: The only way to calculate most given values of $\sqrt{x}, e^x, \sin x, \ln x,...$ is to approximate them. So?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\text{erf}(x)=\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^{\pm\infty}e^{-t^2}$$
using the fact $e^{-t^2}$ is an even function:
$$ \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}$$
The integral is known as the gaussian integral(half of it) and is known to equal $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$ and thus, $$\lim_{z \to \pm\infty} \text{erf}(z) = \pm1$$